# Check whether N is a Fibonacci Series number, starting with numbers a and b instead of 0 and 1

Tags: algorithm, math

I want to check whether a given number 'N' is a part of Fibonacci series starting with integers 'a' and 'b'. When a=0 and b=1, we have the equations 5*N^2 + 4 or 5*N^2 - 4 to be a perfect square. How do we get this formula? Also, is it possible to derive such equations for other values of a and b?

Brute Force Approach- Calculating all the numbers in the series up to N. I want to optimize it further.

Example: N=13, a=2, b=4
Fibonacci Series: 2, 4, 6, 10, 16, ...
Output: Not possible

Comment: It is an interesting question... After a bit research it appears that this formula is generated due to some identities of the golden ratio, so it is possible that there is no formula for general fibonacci series since the golden ratio will not always be involved.

Comment: As stated this is a math exercise, and thus off-topic. But you can certainly read up on Wikipedia and do the math yourself.

Comment: @JamesKPolk Is there any way to take this question and put it in [MathOverFlow](https://mathoverflow.net/)?

Comment: @Yonlif: The only way I know of is to flag it as "in need of moderator attention" with a detailed explanation of what needs to be done. The flag may get rejected, however. By the way, mathoverflow is for Ph.D level math research, this question is more appropriate for math.stackexchange.com

Comment: Oh, ok... Thanks anyway, I guess it will just stay here for now ¯\_(ツ)_/¯.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Identification) wikipedia article you can tell if number is in the Fibonacci series since when putting this number in simplified Binet's formula we need to get a whole n. So what we need to do in order to check if number is in a general Fibonacci series is to create its own general Binet's formula and simplify it. In the same wikipedia article you can find this [general formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Closed-form_expression) (thanks @fjardon), now when simplifying it you get the condition:

```
5 * x^2 +- 4 * (U1 - U0 * (1 - sqrt(5)) / 2) * (U0 * (1 + sqrt(5)) / 2 - U1)
```

Needs to be a perfect square. When `U0` and `U1` are the first and second elements in the series.

> Different approaches

In your case the "Brute Force Approach" might not be that bad. We know that Fibonacci series ratio of consecutive Fibonacci numbers converges to the golden ratio, in a general Fibonacci series it will be a different ratio. Which means that the numbers are getting exponentially big. So if we are iterating over the Fibonacci series we will reach `N` within `log (ratio) (N)` iterations (Assuming you are using dynamic programing to generate the series). So it will be in an approximately logarithmic time.

If you want to improve this you can generate the general formula using [martix form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Matrix_form), that perform [exponential search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_search) in order to find your number. The time complexity here is a bit more complicated since `N` is the number and not it's index but it will be `O(log log N)`.

Comment: The golden ratio will always be involved because it derives from the recurrence formula and not from the initial values. The [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Closed-form_expression) provides a formula for the general case where the initial values are not 0 and 1.

Comment: Oh thats nice @fjardon I didn't notice that when reading the article in the first time. I'll do some calculation and see if there is a generalized form for identification as well.

Comment: I would appreciate if someone will write this in math format since I don't know how.